# Arrow keys not working while entering data for input() function

Tags: python, linux

In linux, the arrow keys don't work when I try to enter data for an `input()` function. I get escape characters. See below (when I pressed left arrow key).

```
dp@hp:~$ python3 -c "x = input('enter a number '); print(x)"
enter a number 123^[[D^[[D
```

I have `readline` installed (I am able to import it in the python shell).
The arrow keys work fine in the interactive interpreter but not in the above case (or when I execute `input()` from a script).

What could be the reason?

Comment: If you are writing a command-line tool, the proper solution is often to have it read command-line arguments (`sys.argv[1:]`) instead of using `input()` interactively.

Answer (score 18):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) says:

> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.

In your example, you haven't loaded the `readline` module.  Compare the behavior of this:

```
x = input('enter a number:')
print(x)
```

To this:

```
import readline
x = input('enter a number:')
print(x)
```

The second example will behave as you expect (readline support is active, arrow keys work, etc) while the first example will not have readline support.

On the command line, this would be:

```
python3 -c "import readline; x=input('enter a number '); print(x)"
```

Comment: You are right. Importing `readline` works. But it should work otherwise too since I have it installed. I am going to try a `pip install` to see if `readline` was installed properly.

Comment: "installed" is not the same as "loaded".  You need to explicitly `import` the module to activate the `readline` support in the `input` function. The documentation says explicitly that the readline module must be "loaded".

Comment: Does this mean I need to import `readline` whenever I use `input()`? This was not needed on Windows...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows, but that is certainly what is implied by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I use linux too and for any module you have to import it.

For example for the readline module I have to do

```
import readline
```

This applies to all modules even the os or sys module I have to do

```
import os
import sys
```

However this only applies to modules that you installed correctly. If you installed readline incorrectly not even

```
import readline
```

will work.

That means for you

```
python3 -c "import readline; x = input('enter a number '); print(x)"
```

if you are doing it straight from the console and this applies to not only readline but every other module that you have and will get.