# Getting Previous Input With Up Arrow in Python Inputs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

#### Problem :

Previously I wrote all of my python code on a Windows 10 machine, but more recently I've been trying to move over to MacOS. Everything is working just fine, with one exception. I'm writing a program that uses the python 'input' function and when pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> on MacOS it prints '^[[a' but on Windows 10 it prints the previous input. Is there get the previous input with the up arrow on Mac?

---

#### Example Code :

```py
while True:
   string = input()
   print(string)
```

On Windows hitting <kbd>↑</kbd> will print the previous input but on Mac '^[[a' will print

Comment: With "previous command" do you mean "previous input"? You shouldn't be able to run commands when you're prompted to input a value for a Python script.

Comment: yes, previous input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772230/arrow-keys-not-working-while-entering-data-for-input-function - windows has built-in support for this, but pretty much everything else requires `readline`.

Comment: To get arrow symbols in Linu and MAC, please use the `readLine` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `readline` module to provide reading and writing of history files. More info on that in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html)

```
import readline

while True:
   string = input()
   print(string)
```